# email post data and base 64 encoded redundant?

Tags: php, email, base64

I have a page that grabs two string variables and sends one, the other is base64 encoded string that it stores on the web server. I also need to send the photo with its caption via an email. I have another page that fires an email...I'm curious how to get the image attached to it.

Target PHP page:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$base = $_POST['image'];


$date = date("Y-m-d");
$name  = "" . $date.rand(0, 999).".jpg";
$path  = "http://192.168.1.5/trendypieces/site/ios/" . $name;

if (file_exists($name)) {
    echo "File already exists";
} else {
    $binary = base64_decode($base);
    $file = fopen($name, 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
    echo "Image uploaded";
}


mysql_select_db("tpwebdata", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO latest (caption, image)
VALUES
('$_POST[caption]','$path')"; 
echo "OK";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }
mysql_close($con)

?>
```

Email page:

```
<?php
$to = "limitedwave@gmail.com"; 
$subject = $_GET['caption'];
$message = "Image: ".$_GET['image'];
$headers = "From: $email"; $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ; 
if($sent) {
    $response = 'Thank you.';
    print 'thanks';
    } 

else {
    $response = 'There has been an error.';
    print 'fail';
    } 
?>
```

I have this for sending a base64 string, but I think it may encode first, in which case I already have it decoded...so I'm kinda lost how to integrate these...

```
function myMail($to, $subject, $mail_msg, $filename, $contentType){

    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: ".$to;
    $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: ".$contentType.
        "; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";

    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)));
    ob_start();

    echo "
--PHP-mixed-$random_hash
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-$random_hash\"

--PHP-alt-$random_hash
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$mail_msg

--PHP-alt-$random_hash

--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--
Content-Type: text/plain; name=\"$filename\" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

$attachment
--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--
";
    $message = ob_get_clean();
    $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
    return $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
}
```

Not sure what part of what I should use to attach the image to an email. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this functions, notice that i manually get the $mime type, its because the getmimetype function is not working on other php version.

```
public static $mime_type = array(
                "doc"       =>    "application/msword",
                "docx"      =>    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
                "pdf"       =>    "application/pdf",
                "xlsx"      =>    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                "gif"       =>    'image/gif',
                "jpg"       =>    'image/jpeg',
                "png"       =>    'image/png',
                "txt"       =>    'text/plain',
                "rtf"       =>    'application/rtf'
);

/*
 * @des    - return mime type base on file extension
 * @notes  - I use this because some of the php function that get the mimetype
 *           is not working on other php version
 * @params string $filename  - full filename of the file e.g. (imat.png)      
 * @return - mime type of the file
 * @requiremetns array $mime_type - an array of file extension with equivalent mime type        
 */

private static function getMimeType($filename)
{
    $filename = basename($filename);
    $ext = explode(".", $filename);
    $ext = $ext[count($ext) - 1];

    return self::$mime_type[$ext];
}


/*
 * @params string $from - this will be the sender of an email
 * @params string $subject - subject of the email
 * @params array $attachments - an array of attachment e.g. array([0] => array("path" => "public_html/imat.com/data/imat.jpg", "filename" => "imat.jpg"))
 * #the attachments["path"] must be an ABSOLUTE PATH
 * @params string $email_message - email message message of the email(can be an html format)
 * @params string $to - this will be the receiver of an email
 * @params string $cc - this will be the carbon copy of the email 
 * @return boolean - return true/false
 */

public static function mail_with_attachment($from, $subject, $attachments, $email_message, $to , $cc = NULL)
{

    $random_hash = sha1(md5(date('r', time()))); 

    //define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n 
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[] = "From: $from";
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
    $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
    $headers   = implode("\r\n", $headers);

    //define the message
    $message = array();
    $message[] = "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash";        
    $message[] = "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-{$random_hash}\"";
    $message[] = "--PHP-alt-{$random_hash}";
    $message[] = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"";
    $message[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";
    $message[] = "\r\n".$email_message."\r\n\r\n";

    foreach($attachments as $attachment)
    {
        $mime_type = self::getMimeType($attachment['filename']);
        $chunk_attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($attachment['path'])));

        $message[] = " \r\n--PHP-mixed-$random_hash";
        $message[] = "Content-Type: $mime_type; name=\"{$attachment['filename']}\"";
        $message[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64";
        $message[] = "Content-Disposition: attachment";
        $message[] = "\r\n".$chunk_attachment."\r\n";
    }

    $message[] = "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash";
    $message   = implode("\r\n", $message);

    //send the email 
    return @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 

}
```

Comment: can't get that to work. isn't all I really need this: $chunk_attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($attachment['path']))); --- but my question is - the page receives a POST variable already that's base64 encoded. can I just say the $chunk_attachment = $_POST[image64encoded] ?

Comment: yes it receives a base64 encoded string. I know you're trying to do an email with attachment. That functions will do. Hope it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with PHPMailer.

```
require '/blahblah/ios/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'limitedwave@gmail.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Store Agent';
$email->Subject   = $_POST['caption'];
$email->Body      = 'the image';
$email->AddAddress( 'limitedwave@gmail.com' );

$file_to_attach = '/blahblah/ios/photos/'.$name.'jpg';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , '2014-03-31221.jpg' );

return $email->Send();
```

However - it doesn't seem to work when integrated with my other code. I suspect its because the email stuff runs before the the process has a chance to decode and save the image on the server.

Does anyone know how I might delay running the email - I'd think I'll put it in a function of course, but how might I wait to call that function until the image is saved?

full code (doesn't attach an image):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("blahblah","tpwebdata","blahblah");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
 // get base64 encoded image from iOS pass vai POST 
$base = $_POST['image'];

// set final URL ($path) for image
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$name  = "" . $date.rand(0, 999).".jpg";
$path  = "http://trendypieces.net/ios/photos/" . $name;

 // save image to location this file resides
if (file_exists($name)) {
    echo "File already exists";
} else {
    $binary = base64_decode($base);
    $file = fopen($name, 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
    echo "Image uploaded";
}

// perform database insert for web site use
mysql_select_db("tpwebdata", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO latest (caption, image)
VALUES
('$_POST[caption]','$path')"; 
echo "OK";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }

// mail it --------------------

require '/blahblah/ios/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'limitedwave@gmail.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Store Agent';
$email->Subject   = $_POST['caption'];
$email->Body      = 'Trendy images.';
$email->AddAddress( 'limitedwave@gmail.com' );

$file_to_attach = '/blahblah/ios/photos/'.$name.'jpg';


$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , '2014-03-31221.jpg' );

return $email->Send();


mysql_close($con);
?>
```